# Is there an alternative to tpu_trainer_lib?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I have been trying to run google's tensor2tensor (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor) locally but it chokes when it gets to this bit:

```
from tensor2tensor.tpu import tpu_trainer_lib
```

Which makes sense because I don't have TPUs in my Mac. Is there an alternative to that function?

Here's the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensor2tensor.tpu'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be able to replace it with :

from tensor2tensor.utils import trainer_lib

And then call the appropriate methods from trainer_lib.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mixed different versions of Tensor2Tensor. In the recent version, there is no `tpu_trainer_lib` (it has been renamed). Even in the few versions where such file existed, it supported training on TPU, GPU and CPU, there are just some if-then-else branches for TPU-specific code.
By the way, TPUs are available currently only for Google employees.